# Need to download a very large amount of data from a database through a web service

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I need to create an action that downloads certain records from my database as a text file. The code below works fine for a toy example (few records). When this code is pushed to production it turns out I run out of memory. Amount of data I deal with is in order of Gbs

```
 public FileResult Streammer()
    {
        MemoryStream file = new MemoryStream();

        using (var db = new DbMapper())
        {
            while (true)
            {
                List<Record> records = db.GetNext(10000);

                if (records == null)
                    break;

                foreach (Record r in records)
                {
                    byte[] data = r.GetBytes();
                    file.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                }
            }
        }

        file.Position = 0;

        return new FileStreamResult(file, "text") { FileDownloadName = "junk.txt" };
    }
```

Ideally, I would like to read chunks of records from the DB on the server. As a single chunk is read it is immediately converted and streamed to a client. The client would show a standard download indicator without actually indicating the remaining time/size.

Any recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't buffer the whole thing in memory first.

Comment: Even if you fix the memory issues server-side, isn't the client then going to have memory issues trying to process it as one very large file? Sounds like you need to break your data up into reasonable sized blocks and handle it fully at both ends.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet for this may be to create a wrapper for your database that inherits from stream and overrides the Read method. Then the FileStream object will pull data from your code instead. You could implement some sort of paging logic so that you don't load the data from the database all at once.